# Long dynamic routes in play framework 2

Tags: java, controller, routes, playframework-2.0

I am developing an app for showing different aspects of cars. The app has a tree-like structure like this:

```
Country>Manufacturer>Model>Car_subsystem>Part
```

I want this structure to be reflected in browser's address bar:

```
http://localhost:9000/Germany/BMW/X6/Body/doors
```

Currently, I do it with play framework's dynamic routing as below:

```
GET /:Country    controllers.Application.controllerFunction(Country : String)
GET /:Country/:Manufacturer     controllers.Application.controllerFunction(Country : String, Manufacturer : String)
```

etc.

This works, but I don't like passing around 5 or 6 parameters to all my controller functions just for the paths to be shown beautifully! Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Dynamic parts spanning several /` as described in [routing doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaRouting)

route:

```
GET   /Cars/*path          controllers.Application.carResolver(path)
```

Action (simplest approach)

```
public static Result carResolver(String path) {
    Car car = Car.findByPath(path);
    return ok(carView.render(car));
}
```

so each car should have its field `path` filled with unique string ID, ie: `Germany/BMW/X6`, Germany/Mercedes/ASL` etc.

Of course it will be much better if you split the `path` arg by the slash first so you can use each part for displaying different views, 'translate' strings to real object ID etc etc.

```
public static Result carResolver(String path) {

    String[] parts = path.split("/");
    int partsLength = parts.length;

    String country = (partsLength > 0) ? parts[0] : null;
    String manufacturer = (partsLength > 1) ? parts[1] : null;
    String carModel = (partsLength > 2) ? parts[2] : null;
    // etc

    switch (partsLength){
        case 0: return countrySelect();
        case 1: return allManufacturersIn(country);
        case 2: return allModelsOf(manufacturer);
        case 3: return singleViewFor(carModel);
        // etc
    }

    return notFound("Didn't find anything for required path...");
}
```

**TIP:** "translating" strings to objects will require from you searching in DB by some field, so there's some advices:

- Try to make sure that each model has a unique field for searching ie. `Country` should have unique `name` as probably you don't want to have Germany 1, Germany 2 etc.
- This approach requires probably more time than searching by numeric ID's so try to cache somehow (mem-cache OR at least dedicated DB table) the result of resolving ie.:

  ```
  Germany/BMW/X6 = Country: 1, Manufacturer: 2, CarModel: 3, action: "singleViewFor"
  ```

Comment: Thanks. this should work.
In my app, each level is represented by a table in DB and has a many-to-one relationship with upper level and each level has various actions (createNew, edit, index).
So your solution works, but I have to implement the logic for different actions on each level in carResolver (e.g editPart, createNewPart, editBody,createNewCountry, etc). It is much cleaner than my own approach, but it still seems to be a lot of work!

What I care about is just to show the user where she stands in the tree. But I guess that's for another question :)